# How to populate a dropdown in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I am a newbie in symfony and i have decided to explore symfony 3. I have two models: products and category and I want to populate a dropdown in a new product form with all the categories. How can i do this pls?
Below is what have done so far:

```
<?php
```

Product Model:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column( type ="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;





    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Category $category
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\AppBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{



    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $products;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;



    public  function __construct()
    {
        $this->products= new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\AppBundle\Entity\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

<

```
?php
DefaultController:
namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Category;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/product_new")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $category = new Category();


        $product = new Product();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('price', NumberType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
                'choices' => $category->getProducts(),
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Create New Product'))
            ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
            {
               // $category->setName( $request->request->get('category'));
                //$product->setCategory( new Category('Cat1'));

                $product = $form->getData();




                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                //$entityManager->persist($category);
                $entityManager->persist($product);



                $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->render('product/product_status.html.twig',
                    ['msg' =>'Saved new product with id ' . $product->getId()]);
            }else
            {
                return $this->render('product/product_new.html.twig', ['form'=> $form->createView(),]);

            }


    }



    /**
     * @Route("/new_product", name="new_product")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName("Keyboard");
        $product->setPrice(19.9);
        $product->setDescription("Ergonomic and stylish!");

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($product);

        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('product/product_status.html.twig',
            ['msg' =>'Saved new product with id ' . $product->getId()]);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/show_product/{productId}")
     */
    public function showAction($productId)
    {
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($productId);

        if(!$product)
        {
            $this->createNotFoundException("No Product was found with Id". $productId);
        }
            return $this->render('product/product_search.html.twig', ['product' => $product]);

    }


    /**
     * @Route("/product_list", name ="productlist")
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->findAll();

        if(!$products)
        {
            $this->createNotFoundException("No Product was found ");
        }
        return $this->render('product/product_list.html.twig', ['products' => $products]);

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/update_product/{productId}", name ="updateproduct")
     */
    public function updateAction($productId)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($productId);

        if($product)
        {
            $product->setName("Project");
            $product->setDescription("Sony Projector with LCD light");

            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('productlist');

        }

    }


    /**
     * @Route("/delete_product/{productId}", name ="deleteproduct")
     */
    public function deleteAction($productId)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->find($productId);

        if($product)
        {
           $entityManager->remove($product);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('productlist');

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: use form entityType field http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Remove the `choices` option in your `category` field and you will have all the category listed. Look http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage

Comment: Thanks @DFayet. It worked when i replaced the choices option

Answer (score 1):

You can use [query_builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) option like below. You can adapt it to your application. Full example is here: [Full webform style CRUD example with an embedded associated entity in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/djrc/full-webform-style-crud-example-with-an-embedded-associated-entity-in-symfony)

```
....
    private $country;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->country = [
            ....
            'class' => 'FootballFrontendBundle:Country',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo)
            {
                return $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
            }
        ];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = [])
    {
        $builder
            ....
            ->add('country', 'entity', $this->country);
    }

....
```